# Unable to import google_play_services using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to get adds from internet and installed `google_play_services` and `Google APIs` (Android 4.4.2, API 19). But when I am importing `google_play_services` library from  path <`sdk_home>\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services` in eclipse, getting message that "`No projects are found to import`". Moreover I checked manually in path `<sdk_home>\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130917\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs` I found only `google-play-services.jar` and `google-play-services.jar.properties` but not `google-play-services-lib.jar`.

When I ran the project, in log file I am getting error `google play services not available due to error 2`. I found many threads on this but nothing seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I am following that link only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. although it is saying "`google services are not available due to error 2`"  I was trying to add as a project not as an `android existing code`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you have already imported the `google-play-services_lib` project and just deleted from `eclipse IDE` but not in your hard drive workspace folder. Try deleting the `google-play-services_lib` project from your Workspace folder and try importing the project again.

**`And make sure "Is Library" is checked in properties->Android of google-play-services_lib project.`**